# Where is the FK/IK switch?

Tags: rigging

Can't find the IK/FK switch on this rig, (it says it has).

http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/73740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to right click the base; the IK/FK panel will be on the right side.

0 = IK on

1 = FK on

[image]